# Are there similar datasets to MNIST?

Tags: machine-learning, mnist

I am doing research on machine learning. Now I want to test my algorithms with some famous datasets. Since I am a newbie in this area, I can't find other suitable datasets apart from MNIST. I thing MNIST is quite suitable for our research. Does anyone know some similar datasets with MNIST?

P.S I know another handwritten digit dataset that is often used, called USPS dataset. But I need a dataset with more training examples (typically more than 10000 and comparable to the number of training examples in MNIST), so USPS is out of my selection.

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. MNIST is a great dataset that contains handwritten digits. Do you want to work on handwritten digits or something else (faces, handwritten letters, etc)?

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 5):

The machine learning archive (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) contains quite a variety of datasets including those, like MINIST,  suitable for classification e.g. (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Skin+Segmentation).

I can't say which of them would be suitable without knowing what you're trying to demonstrate with your algorithm but anything inside the UCI archive is well known.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Fashion MNIST](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist) or [Kuzushiji MNIST](https://github.com/rois-codh/kmnist) that have very similar properties to MNIST, but a bit harder to predict. From Fashion MNIST's page:

> Seriously, we are talking about replacing MNIST. Here are some good reasons:
>
> - MNIST is too easy. Convolutional nets can achieve 99.7% on MNIST. Classic machine learning algorithms can also achieve 97% easily. Check out our side-by-side benchmark for Fashion-MNIST vs. MNIST, and read "Most pairs of MNIST digits can be distinguished pretty well by just one pixel."
> - MNIST is overused. In this April 2017 Twitter thread, Google Brain research scientist and deep learning expert Ian Goodfellow calls for people to move away from MNIST.
> - MNIST can not represent modern CV tasks, as noted in this April 2017 Twitter thread, deep learning expert/Keras author François Chollet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I hope my suggestions can still be useful. I was also looking for datasets similar to handwritten MNIST and Fashion MINIST as well. Pytorch provides several of them with documentation: [KMNIST](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.KMNIST.html#torchvision.datasets.KMNIST), [QMNIST](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.QMNIST.html#torchvision.datasets.QMNIST), [USPS](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.USPS.html#torchvision.datasets.USPS), [SEMEION](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.SEMEION.html#torchvision.datasets.SEMEION), [SVHN](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.SVHN.html#torchvision.datasets.SVHN), amongst others. Check [here for the full list](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/datasets.html).